# Small problem about domain of a function .

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I want to know that whether $f:\mathbb{R}^2/\lbrace(0,0)\rbrace \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x,y) = \arctan(\frac{x}{y})$ is a function or not?

I think this is very silly problem but i think it is not a function. can anyone explain it?

Comment: Well, what is $f(x,0)$?

Comment: @M.B  it is $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ acc as $x \gt 0$ or $x \lt 0$

Comment: am right or wrong?

Comment: On what domain?

Comment: $f$ is a function any $(x,y)$ maps to at most one $z$.  Now, in this case $f$ may not be defined for some values of $(x,y)$ other than $(0,0)$.  But can you see any possibility of a single $(x,y)$ mapping to two different $z$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first notice that $\frac{x}{y}$ is not defined for $y=0$, so you should not consider in the domain the set $A = \{(x, y) : y = 0\}$.

Now, you should verify when the function $f(z) = arctan(z)$ is well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

[image] Not sure what to say for minimum length.
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arctan%28x%2Fy%29

Answer (score 1):

The expression $\arctan(\frac{x}{y})$ is not defined for $y=0$, so with that as the definition your $f$ will only be defined on $\mathbb R\times(\mathbb R\setminus\{0\})$. But on that set it assign exactly one value to each pair $(x,y)$ and that makes it a function.

If you want a function that has the values you mention in a comment, you need to define it explicit to have those:
$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\pi}{2} & \text{if}\ y=0\ \text{and}\ x>0\\
-\frac{\pi}{2} & \text{if}\ y=0\ \text{and}\ x<0\\
\arctan(\frac{x}{y}) & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make sense as stated. The notation $f:\mathbb{R}^2/\lbrace(0,0)\rbrace \to \mathbb{R}$ means that $f$ is a function with domain $\mathbb{R}^2/\lbrace(0,0)\rbrace$ and codomain $\mathbb R.$ You surely didn't mean to ask "is this function a function?"

Now the question "Is the expression $\arctan (x/y)$ well defined for all $(x,y) \ne (0,0)?$" makes sense. The answer is no it isn't, because the expression is meaningless for all $(x,y)$ with $y=0.$